# When is Taylor series substitution valid?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Given that the Maclaurin series for $g(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$ is $1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 ... $, I'm told that the Maclaurin series for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 ... $, by substituting in $x^2$.

What I'm confused about is why this is valid for this case specifically and what rules govern when you can and can't do something like this -- for example, you couldn't do it with the series for $x$ itself and substitute in, say, $cos(x) = x$, right?

Comment: Technically, $\cos(x)$ is a "series" in the variable $\cos(x)$ which sums up to $\cos(x)$. But it isn't a power series.

Comment: In general I think you are asking when you can assume a power series form of solution. The mathematicians' answer is that you have to know that the result is analytic (which in practice is a very strong assumption). The physicists' answer is more complicated and usually more ad hoc. (Either they just assume it blindly, they check it rigorously, or actually it *doesn't* work but there is some regularization technique that makes it "morally" work.)

Comment: So that wouldn't even be a Maclaurin series, right? Which means the substitution doesn't work there -- which ties back to my question of when is and isn't a substitution like that valid?

Comment: It's just as valid as ever...but it doesn't get you a power series. Are you asking about when the result will get you a power series?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose -- more generally, when will performing such a substitution get a result that is a correct power series, and when will such a substitution be useful in solving problems?

Comment: Don't write $x=\cos x$ - that is not what you mean at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^n= \frac{1}{1-x}
$$
for all $\lvert x\rvert < 1$. So, whenever $x$ is something that has an absolute value less than $1$, then you have this equality. If you replace $x$ by $x^2$, then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  (x^2)^n = \frac{1}{1-x^2}
$$
and this is true when $\lvert x^2\rvert < 1$. You also have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  (\cos(x))^n = \frac{1}{1 - \cos(x)}
$$
for all $x$ such that $\lvert \cos(x)\rvert < 1$.

And you have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  (-x)^n = \frac{1}{1 + x}
$$
for all $x$ where $\lvert -x\rvert = \lvert x \rvert < 1$ (This is the series that you are considering. These all "come from" the first series.